How does QtAsyncio.run() know what to run?
Full code for this example is below. I'm more interested in this part:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()

    QtAsyncio.run()

How does QtAsyncio.run() know what to run? nothing is passed to it.
# Copyright (C) 2022 The Qt Company Ltd.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: LicenseRef-Qt-Commercial OR BSD-3-Clause

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)

import PySide6.QtAsyncio as QtAsyncio

import asyncio
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)

        self.text = QLabel("The answer is 42.")
        layout.addWidget(self.text, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

        async_trigger = QPushButton(text="What is the question?")
        async_trigger.clicked.connect(lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(self.set_text()))
        layout.addWidget(async_trigger, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

    async def set_text(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        self.text.setText("What do you get if you multiply six by nine?")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()

    QtAsyncio.run()


See https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/sources/pyside6/PySide6/QtAsyncio/init.py?id=94c21428779b5433d84c77d7b42d3652c4228709#n20

It just runs the default asyncio event loop.

@Barmar I don't see where app is added to the event loop and it's not started with app.exec()

I think async_trigger.clicked.connect(lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(self.set_text()))

https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/sources/pyside6/PySide6/QtAsyncio/init.py?id=94c21428779b5433d84c77d7b42d3652c4228709#n20; See QAsyncioEventLoopPolicy and https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/sources/pyside6/PySide6/QtAsyncio/events.py?id=94c21428779b5433d84c77d7b42d3652c4228709#n187

@Barmar that would certainly add the self.set_text() function to the loop. But that would only happen if the app is being executed and again I don't see how that is being launched

It happens when you call MainWindow() since it's in the __init__() method.

@iamthebull The QtAsyncio module provides several classes that implement Python's asyncio event-loop. When you call QtAsyncio.run(), it will create an internal instance of QAsyncioEventLoopPolicy, which will in turn create an instance of QAsyncioEventLoop. These classes ensure that when run calls asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever(), it will also eventually call QCoreApplication.instance().exec().

@iamthebull The assumption is that there should always be only just one Qt application instance (QCoreApplication, QGuiApplication or QApplication) for each "program" (process). Therefore, any code, including that of imported modules, can just use QCoreApplication.instance() to retrieve that instance (if one exists) without any declaration, definition or argument. That's also the reason for which a Qt application should always be created only within a if __name__ == '__main__': expression, possibly checking if none already exists.

@ekhumoro musicamante thanks that's helpful. Does the asyncio event loop replace the one the qt application would normally use?

@iamthebull No - QtAsyncio replaces the default asyncio event-loop with a Qt one. This allows asyncio operations to be integrated with the normal Qt event-loop.
